# Calculate the matrix of square of a sum in R

Tags: r, microbenchmark

I hope this is not a duplicated question. I wanted to calculate the square of a sum of a vector in a matrix form. For example, I have a vector:

`v = c(a, b, c, d)`

What I wanted to achieve is a matrix form of the equation expansion (a+b+c+d)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2ab + 2ac + 2ad + 2bc + 2bd + 2cd as:

```
a^2  ab   ac   ad
ab   b^2  bc   bd
ac   bc   c^2  cd
ad   bd   cd   d^2
```

Is there a function in r to do so without writing it out by hand?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Try `v %*% t(v)`

Comment: @MartinGal Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you want is outer product:

```
v <- 1:5
outer(v, v, '*')
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
#[3,]    3    6    9   12   15
#[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
#[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

Benchmarking different approaches:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
v <- 1:1000
mbm <- microbenchmark("outer" = { outer(v, v, '*') },
                      "matprod" = { v%*%t(v)   },
                      "tcrossprod" = { tcrossprod(v)})
autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]

The above figure shows `outer()` and direct matrix product to be more efficient than `tcrossprod()`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```r
v = 1:4
tcrossprod(v)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4
#> [2,]    2    4    6    8
#> [3,]    3    6    9   12
#> [4,]    4    8   12   16
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much!